# Can I keep upstart while upgrading to 16.04.1 via `sudo do-release-upgrade`?

Tags: upstart, systemd, do-release-upgrade

I have a server which has some services configured via upstart scripts. I think it would be good to do the upgrade to 16.04, but I'd rather not rewrite them all to systemd right now. Can upstart coexist with systemd? Can `sudo do-release-upgrade` command be tweaked to leave upstart installed?

Comment: Upstart will still be installed, but I doubt the services will work. Exactly why do you think it "would be good to do the upgrade to 16.04"?

Comment: @mikewhatever because I've heard that some new software will only be available to newer versions (especially if it's "snap" packages), also there can be newer security patches and so on. Also, its support ends 2 years later.